# Director Lingo Problems - See Code

Tags: if-statement, statements, lingo, adobe-director

I am trying to use if statements to go to two different frames in the Director game project but eventhough I have go to frame 32 for one set and go to frame 31 for another, they are both going to the same frame 31.  What am I doing wrong?  I can't figure it out.  (see the code example here:)

--

```
on timeOut


  if the timer >= 360 and sprite(16).visible = 1 then
    member ("tellIt").text = "TIME UP"
    _movie.go(32)


  end if

  if the timer >= 360 and sprite(15).visible = 1 then
    member ("tellIt").text = "TIME UP"
    _movie.go(32)


  end if

  if the timer >= 360 and sprite(14).visible = 1 then
    member ("tellIt").text = "TIME UP"
    _movie.go(32)

  end if

  if the timer >= 360  and sprite(13).visible = 1 then
    member ("tellIt").text = "TIME UP"
    _movie.go(32 
  end if

if the timer > 350 and sprite(16).visible = 0 then
    _movie.go(31)
    member ("endIt").text = "LUNCH IS FOR THE BIRDS"
    member ("tellIt").text = "TIME FLIES"
  end if

  if the timer > 350 and sprite(15).visible = 0 then
    _movie.go(31)
    member ("endIt").text = "LUNCH IS FOR THE BIRDS"
    member ("tellIt").text = "TIME FLIES"
  end if

  if the timer > 350 and sprite(14).visible = 0 then
    _movie.go(31)
    member ("endIt").text = "LUNCH IS FOR THE BIRDS"
    member ("tellIt").text = "TIME FLIES"
  end if

  if the timer > 350  and sprite(13).visible = 0 then
    _movie.go(31)
    member ("endIt").text = "LUNCH IS FOR THE BIRDS"
    member ("tellIt").text = "TIME FLIES"
  end if

  if the timer > 350  and sprite(12).visible = 0 then
    _movie.go(31)
    member ("endIt").text = "LUNCH IS FOR THE BIRDS"
    member ("tellIt").text = "TIME FLIES"
  end if
--
```

This code is written on the movie script.

I really hope you can steer me in the right direction as I don't have a clue why it's not going to the frame I am asking it to.  Everything else in the game appears to be working fine.

Comment: wouldn't you want to use an else statement?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it, it doesn't matter how many of the first checks are true, if any one of the later checks are true, then you're going to end up at frame 31.

If you put an 'exit' in each of the if statements, that will make sure that the later checks are not done. Like:

```
if the timer >= 360 and sprite(16).visible = 1 then
   member ("tellIt").text = "TIME UP"
   _movie.go(32)
   exit
end if
```